# Shinyloadtest: Error: Please upgrade your pandoc version to be at least v2.2

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, pandoc

I am trying to run results from recording.log, as instructed from https://rstudio.github.io/shinyloadtest/ I am running below command to see in browser view:

```
shinyloadtest::shinyloadtest_report(df, "run1.html")
```

but throwing an error :

[image]

to resolve this, when I am trying install pandoc, throwing below error

[image]

what I am doing wrong in this?

can any one please help me on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Issue was resolved, I have used one command in R Studio that can overpass `pandoc` issue:

```
shinyloadtest_report(df,"run1.html",self_contained=F)
```